# dynamically select as checked a specific checkbox in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some checkboxes with dynamic `data-price` generated using `PHP`.
OnClick of this checkbox, I update a `div` that display the price.

I want to be able to display the data-price with minimum value when the DOM is ready and, of course, that my checkbox wit the minimum value of price starts checked.

Here's my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".price").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#showPrice").html( $(this).attr('data-price') +' €' );
        
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="price" type="checkbox" data-price="1000">item 1<br>
<input class="price" type="checkbox" data-price="200">item 2<br>
<input class="price" type="checkbox" data-price="6000">item 3<br>
<br><br><br>
<div id="showPrice">0000 €</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With array.reduce it can be easily solved

```js
const checkboxes = $('.price').get();

if (checkboxes.length > 0) {
  const min = checkboxes.reduce(function(minCheckbox, checkbox) {
    if ($(checkbox).data('price') < $(minCheckbox).data('price')) {
      return checkbox;
    }
    
    return minCheckbox;
  }, checkboxes[0]);
  
  $(min).attr('checked', 'checked');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="price" type="checkbox" data-price="1000">item 1<br>
<input class="price" type="checkbox" data-price="200">item 2<br>
<input class="price" type="checkbox" data-price="6000">item 3<br>
<br><br><br>
<div id="showPrice">0000 €</div>
```

Comment: maybe i wan unclear, but i don't know which of those input is the minimum because those input will be generated in php.. maybe I will have 15 of them or maybe I will have one.

Comment: i updated original comment with a solution to check the min checkbox, i think also the way you are handling the clcik events is wrong.
Have you considered using a <select> instead of checkboxes?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".price").click(function (e) {
    $('input.price').on('change', function () {
      $('input.price').not(this).prop('checked', false);
    });
    $("#showPrice").html($(this).attr('data-price') + ' €');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="price" type="checkbox" data-price="1000">item 1<br>
<input class="price" type="checkbox" data-price="200">item 2<br>
<input class="price" type="checkbox" data-price="6000">item 3<br>
<br><br><br>
<div id="showPrice">0000 €</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate the input values and check the one that has the lowest value. Remember to use parseInt() or similar function to ensure you are running a numeric comparison.

EDIT: Corrected to find the lowest value where initial code found the highest value.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".price").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#showPrice").html( $(this).data('price') +' €' );
        
    });
    
    // ensure nothing is checked
    $(".price").prop('checked', false);
    
    // iterate the elements to find the smallest numeric value of data('price')
    var obj, upperVal, minVal, domVal;
    upperVal = 99999999;
    minVal = upperVal;
    $(".price").each( function(){
      domVal = parseInt($(this).data('price'), 10);
      if (domVal < minVal){
        minVal = domVal;
        obj = $(this);
      }
    })
    
    // if minval is < upperVal then we got a hit
    if (minVal < upperVal){
      obj.prop('checked', true);
    }
    

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="price" type="checkbox" data-price="1000">item 1 (1000)<br>
<input class="price" type="checkbox" data-price="200">item 2 (200)<br>
<input class="price" type="checkbox" data-price="6000">item 3 (6000)<br>
<br><br><br>
<div id="showPrice">0000 €</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var min = 1000000;
    var minPriceCheckedBox;
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $(".price").each(function() {
        var val = $(this).data("price");
        if (val < min ) {
          min = val;
          minPriceCheckedBox = $(this);
        }
        
       });

       minPriceCheckedBox.prop("checked",true);
       $("#showPrice").html( minPriceCheckedBox.attr('data-price') +' €' );
        $(".price").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#showPrice").html( $(this).attr('data-price') +' €' );
            
        });
      });
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <input class="price" type="checkbox" data-price="1000">item 1<br>
      <input class="price" type="checkbox" data-price="200">item 2<br>
      <input class="price" type="checkbox" data-price="6000">item 3<br>
      <br><br><br>
      <div id="showPrice">0000 €</div>
```